# Can I use node.js server modules in webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Can we import all `node.js` modules in webpack and create a `bundle.js`? Example what if I use `http` module and webpack application and bundle it and run in browser?

**`main.js`**

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // send output
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Node's built-in libraries with Webpack, it will automatically import a browser-compatible version when available.

You can see the entire list and matching packages in [this file](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/blob/master/index.js).

For `http`, you'll end up with [`http-browserify`](https://github.com/substack/http-browserify) instead. Not everything is supported, so creating a HTTP server will not work (as this isn't possible in a browser). You can still use `http` to do requests as shown in the documentation.

Comment: thanks , i got it, but it does not give any error during building process, i got error in browser, that's why think thought that why this happening  :)